# Google App Engine for Java development server SocketTimeoutException from UrlFetch to url that responds with code 204

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an issue where using the GAE development server. I am seeing timeouts when doing a url fetch to a URL that responds with a 204. And after a few such requests the development server stops responding all together. FYI all is fine on the production server.

Sample code is:-

```
URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
HTTPResponse response = fetcher.fetch(new URL("some/url/that/responds/with/204"));
```

This throws the following:-

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Timeout while fetching: some/url/that/responds/with/204
```

However, the "some/url/that/responds/with/204" responds with the 204 straight away, and increasing the timeout doesn't help. If I get the same URL to respond with 200 all is fine, and all is fine on the production server. I.e. I get the 204 as expected in a few ms on the production server.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: several things are partially broken on the development server. I've responded by always trying on the deployed instance and if that works then forget about the local version for that feature.

Comment: @Paul, thanks for the info, I'm starting to realise the dev-server is broken in a few places, I'll take your suggestion on board.